# MS Access with VBA don't edit the row

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a function in a module to get data from a third part software. And I have a sub fuction to get more data from the same third part software. Instead of editing the same row, the sub fuction only add a new row with the information retrieve from the other software. But I need the information in the row that already has in the table.

Its the code from the sub function.

```
Sub Entregue()
Dim base As Database
Dim Itens_Sislog As Recordset

Set base = CurrentDb()
Set Itens_Sislog = base.OpenRecordset("Itens_Sislog")

Dim i As Integer
Dim linha As Integer

If Copiar(1, 2, 8) = "SLCM0750" Then
Colar 13, 3, "X"
Teclar "@E"
End If

If Copiar(1, 2, 8) = "SLCM0751" Then
Itens_Sislog.Edit 
Itens_Sislog("Entregue_em") = Copiar(14, 9, 11)
Itens_Sislog.Update
Teclar "@3"
Teclar "@3"
End If

End Sub
```

If I change this *Itens_Sislog.Edit* to this *Itens_Sislog.addnew*,  it works and add new information. But I want to edit the row to add this new information into another column not to another row.

Edit:
The function and sub work at the same time ( I don'to know if this information is important.)
When I use the .addnew that is the result:

[Capture of the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AI99n.png)

Anyone has a clue?

Comment: you need a where condition & a loop to tell which row(s) to update.

Comment: As a newbie, I didn't be clear in my explanation.  I edited the post.

Answer (score 0):

You are just opening the recordset, so any edit will be of the first record only.

Do first a search:

```
Itens_Sislog.FindFirst "SomeField = " & SomeValue & ""    ' or for text:
Itens_Sislog.FindFirst "SomeField = '" & SomeValue & "'"
```

to find the record to edit.

For examples etc., the doc is alive:

[Recordset.FindFirst method (DAO)](https://learn.microsoft.com/da-dk/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/recordset-findfirst-method-dao)

Comment: I paste this in the code, but it doesn't work. Is expected to change something in the "somefield" and "SomeValue" values when adding this code to the sub function?

Comment: Yes, it was just a hint. The documentation is your friend - see edited answer, please.